# How to add more zoom steps without increasing maxzoom value

Tags: openlayers-3

I am working with Openlayers 3.7 and I have a map with the following settings on the view:
`zoom: 2,
maxZoom: 4,
minZoom: 1`

Is posible to have more zoom "steps"? So instead of having only 4 steps (1, 2, 3 and 4), have for example 7 (1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5 and 4). So this means going from integer values to float values. The current configuration covers the zoom that I want, so adding a higher value on maxZoom isn't a solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this - https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3684

Comment: Thank you for the link @JonatasWalker.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @JonatasWalker link, the solution to my problem was the "zoomFactor" property and increase the "maxZoom" value.